# Middle-click scrolling in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been using VS Code to build my portfolio site and I've actually found it to be much more efficient than Visual Studio, I mean, once I've got the vNext boilerplate stuff all setup. But I need the middle-click-to-scroll functionality that everybody seems to be taking away from us lately.

I read on another SO answer that they weren't happy with their plugin api so they haven't released it yet, but are there any shortcuts, options or hidden *things* that could allow me to enable middle-click scrolling? Or is there a secret way to enable plugin support so I could write my own or download a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually no way to enable middle click scrolling. 
The extension API is about to be opened for public usage. Just give them a bit of time to round everything up.

Comment: Ok, I'll accept that for now. Thanks @Wosi. I really hope they add support for it.

Comment: it's been 5 years, any actual solutions? Sick of having to manually horizontal scrolling with the scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this open GitHub issue thread in vscode repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/104183), as of September 2021 this <s>feature is not implemented</s> bug is not fixed. However, there is [this AutoHotKey workaround.](https://github.com/qooqu/vs-code-mbutton-scroll-ahk). For the sake of completeness of the answer, here is source code, which is licensed under [GNU General Public License v3.0](https://github.com/qooqu/vs-code-mbutton-scroll-ahk/blob/main/LICENSE) by original author:

```
; autohotkey script to enable middle mouse button scrolling in VS Code
; with the cursor in a text area, hold down the middle mouse button to scroll
; outside of text areas, middle mouse is unaffected

#IfWinActive ahk_exe Code.exe ; script is only active in VS Code
    MButton:: ; on middle mouse button click, do the following
        ; check if the cursor is in a text area
        ; if no, send a regular middle click
        ; if yes, scroll
        if (A_Cursor != "IBeam") {
            send {MButton}
        } else {
            scroll := true ; activate scroll
            noScrollZone := 10 ; no scrolling until the mouse moves at least this far
            MouseGetPos, xinit , yinit ; initial position of cursor when middle mouse button is clicked
            while scroll { ; loop until middle mouse button is released
                ToolTip, SCROLLING ; visual indication that scroll is active
                MouseGetPos, x , y ; current position of cursor
                ; check the four cases
                if (y < yinit - noScrollZone) ; up
                    send, {WheelUp 1}
                if (y > yinit + noScrollZone) ; down
                    send, {WheelDown 1}
                if (x < xinit - noScrollZone) ; left
                    send, {WheelLeft 1}
                if (x > xinit + noScrollZone) ; right
                    send, {WheelRight 1}
                ; make speed of scroll react to cursor position
                dist := Round( Sqrt( ( x - xinit )**2 + ( y - yinit )**2 ) ) ; cursor's distance from initial position
                sleepTime := Max( 300 - dist, 0 ) ; a lower sleeptime gives a faster scroll
                ; sleepTime:= 100 ; uncomment this line to get a constant scroll speed
                sleep sleepTime ; loop pauses for this length of time
            }
        }
    return
#IfWinActive

#IfWinActive ahk_exe Code.exe ; script is only active in VS Code
    MButton Up:: ; on middle mouse button release, do the following
        scroll := false ; cancel scroll
        ToolTip ; cancel tooltip
    return
#IfWinActive
```

However, this does not have smooth scrolling. The scrolling kind of... jumps. But it's the best we have right now.